# How to add non-escaped ampersands to HTML with Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Tags: html, xml, utf-8, escaping, nokogiri

I would like to add things like bullet points "•" to HTML using the XML Builder in Nokogiri, but everything is being escaped.  How do I prevent it from being escaped?

I would like the result to be:

```
<span>&#8226;</span>
```

rather than:

```
<span>&amp;#8226;</span>
```

I'm just doing this:

```
xml.span { 
  xml.text "&#8226;\ " 
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define

```
  class Nokogiri::XML::Builder
    def entity(code)
      doc = Nokogiri::XML("<?xml version='1.0'?><root>&##{code};</root>")
      insert(doc.root.children.first)
    end
  end
```

then this

```
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
    xml.span {
      xml.text "I can has "
      xml.entity 8665
      xml.text " entity?"
    }
  end
  puts builder.to_xml
```

yields

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<span>I can has &#x2022; entity?</span>
```

**PS** this a workaround only, for a clean solution please refer to the `libxml2` documentation (Nokogiri is built on libxml2) for more help. However, even these folks [admit that handling entities can be quite ..err, cumbersome sometimes](http://xmlsoft.org/entities.html).

Comment: thanks adrian, what is an "entity", and where'd you get 8665?

Comment: if I do 8226 instead of 8665, it parses it to "bull;" :/

Comment: Oops, I mistook 8665 for 8226! 
Entity is the proper name for `&thing;` sequences. 
`&bull;` should be okay, it's the official name of that entity in HTML. 
`<!ENTITY bull CDATA "&#8226;" -- bullet, =black small circle, u+2022 ISOpub -->` see http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/sgml/entities.html

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting the text of an element, you really are setting text, not HTML source. `<` and `&` don't have any special meaning in plain text.

So just type a bullet: `'•'`. Of course your source code and your XML file will have to be using the same encoding for that to come out right. If your XML file is UTF-8 but your source code isn't, you'd probably have to say `'\xe2\x80\xa2'` which is the UTF-8 byte sequence for the bullet character as a string literal.

(In general non-ASCII characters in Ruby 1.8 are tricky. The byte-based interfaces don't mesh too well with XML's world of all-text-is-Unicode.)

Comment: I need to have the result with "&#8226;", so '\xe2\x80\xa2' isn't working :/

Comment: Why do you *need* that particular escaped version? If you are having encoding troubles so the • doesn't appear like you type it, then you should try to fix those by setting your encoding right rather than resorting to HTML-escapes. (Whilst in other environments you might ask your HTML serialiser to escape all non-ASCII characters to HTML-ampersand-sequences to get around this, Ruby doesn't currently have that level of Unicode support.)